# create monthly report from items table and daily movements table

Tags: mysql

Please, my request is to create a monthly report table from items table and daily transactions table

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select i.id,i.code.i.item_name ,
       sum(if(m.action='purchased',m.quantity,0)) as total_purchased,
       sum(if(m.action='sold',m.quantity,0))*-1 as total_sold,
       sum(if(m.action='purchased',m.quantity,0))+sum(if(m.action='sold',m.quantity,0)) as balance
from items i
inner join movements m on i.code=m.code
group by i.code;
```

Comment: thank you Code-Monk,, this helped me to know how to solve like this in the future...